# C++ The procedure entry point CLRCreateInstance could not be located in the dynamic link library mscoree.dll

Tags: c++, .net, clr

I have the following code which checks CLR versions installed on the PC.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
#import <mscorlib.tlb> raw_interfaces_only auto_rename
#include <metahost.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "Mscoree" )

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ICLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost);
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ICLRRuntimeInfo, IID_ICLRRuntimeInfo);

int checkCLRversion()
{
    ICLRMetaHostPtr pMetaHost{ nullptr };
    HRESULT hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -1;

    IEnumUnknownPtr enumptr{ nullptr };
    hr = pMetaHost->EnumerateInstalledRuntimes(&enumptr);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -1;

    while (true)
    {
        ULONG fetched{ 0 };
        IUnknownPtr uptr{ nullptr };
        hr = enumptr->Next(1, &uptr, &fetched);
        if (hr == S_OK)
        {
            ICLRRuntimeInfoPtr crlri{ uptr };
            DWORD size{ 0 };
            hr = crlri->GetVersionString(nullptr, &size);
            if (hr == HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) && size > 0)
            {
                std::wstring version(size, 0);
                hr = crlri->GetVersionString(&version.front(), &size);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    std::wcout << version << std::endl;                    
                }
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    };
    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    HMODULE clrInst = LoadLibraryA("C:\\Windows\\System32\\mscoree.dll");
    if (GetProcAddress(clrInst, "CLRCreateInstance") != NULL)
    {
        checkCLRversion();
    }
}
```

It builds fine and works almost on all machines, but if I try to run this application on Win 7 machine without installed Service Pack 1 I get the error "The procedure entry point CLRCreateInstance could not be located in the dynamic link library mscoree.dll".
[image: Text]

In the function main() I've added a condition

```
if (GetProcAddress(clrInst, "CLRCreateInstance") != NULL)
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: .NET version >= 4.0 required.  Win7 originally shipped with 3.5

Comment: But because of condition in main function the code goes another way and doesn't do stuff that requires .NET 4. And anyway I have this error

Comment: You can't get that far, it fails before main() can start running.  The loader can't bind the CLRCreateInstance() function call.  If you want to dynamically check then you also have to dynamically invoke.

Comment: @HansPassant but how to do this?:)

Comment: You need a function pointer.  metahost.h already declares one, CLRCreateInstanceFnPtr fp = (CLRCreateInstanceFnPtr)GetProcAddress(...);